# Compare two algorithms with each other

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, asymptotics

I am fairly new algorithms and the math behind it.

I am very sorry if this is the wrong place to ask if so please let me know and I can delete this question.

I would need help with the following algorithms.

The task is to choose `α` so that `B` is asymptotically faster than `A`.

> A: $\ T_a$(n) = 7$T_a$($\frac{n}{2}$)+n²
>
> B: $\ T_b$(n) = α$T_b$($\frac{n}{4}$)+n²

I have tried to figure out what the asymptotically upper bound would be and I have come up with this formula for A:

> A: T(n) = n² + $\sum_{k=1}^k 7^{k-1} \frac{(n^2)}{2^k}+7^kT(\frac{n}{2^k})$

k is for n < 2 = ld(n)

But I do not understand how to go on from here.

Any help would be very apricated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), you can solve it easily. From the master theorem as $c_{crit} = \log_27 \sim  2.81$ we know that $A = O(n^{2.81}) = \Theta(n^{\log_27})$. Hence, if $a = 4^2 = 16$, from master thorem $B = \Theta(n^2\log(n))$ and asymptotically faster than $A$. Also, for all $a < 16$ this would be true.